# Understanding gometalinter unconvert unnecessary conversion warning

Tags: go

`warning: unnecessary conversion (unconvert)`

This comes from the following line:

`offsetY += 60 + image.Image(*img.Bitmap).Bounds().Max.Y`

It took me a while to understand how to convert this interface pointer to an interface yet I do not think that this is the right solution since gometalinter raises a warning.

I want to get the width of the `img`.
`img` is of struct `Image` and has a Bitmap pointer to a real `image.Image` (image stdlib). If I want to call `Bounds` on the actual `image.Image` I need to transform the pointer to the interface into an interface.

How should that be done in a more go friendly way?

I have the following go code:

```
import (
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "image/draw"
)
type Image struct {
    Src    string
    Title  string
    Width  int
    Height int
    Index  int
    Bitmap *image.Image
}

type Images []Image

offsetY = 10
func ComposeImage(imgs Images) image.Image {
    masterRGBAImg := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 300, 300))
    masterBounds := masterRGBAImg.Bounds()

    for _, img := range imgs {
        draw.Draw(masterRGBAImg, masterBounds,
            *img.Bitmap, image.Point{X: -10, Y: -offsetY + 10}, draw.Src)


        addLabel(masterRGBAImg, 10, offsetY-30, img.Title)

        // HERE ======
        offsetY += 60 + image.Image(*img.Bitmap).Bounds().Max.Y
        // END ======

    }
    return masterRGBAImg
}

// Draw label on image.
func addLabel(img *image.RGBA, x int, y int, label string) {
    col := color.RGBA{50, 50, 50, 255}
    point := fixed.Point26_6{X: fixed.Int26_6(x * 64), Y: fixed.Int26_6(y * 64)}

    d := &font.Drawer{
        Dst:  img,
        Src:  image.NewUniform(col),
        Face: inconsolata.Bold8x16,
        Dot:  point,
    }
    d.DrawString(label)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the bitmap field is a `*image.Image`, so it's of the same type and you don't need to convert it when you could just dereference it.

```
(*img.Bitmap).Bounds()
```

However, `image.Image` is an interface. A pointer to an interface is almost always a programming error.

Change your struct definition to

```
type Image struct {
    Src    string
    Title  string
    Width  int
    Height int
    Index  int
    Bitmap image.Image
}
```

and you can then just call `img.Bitmap.Bounds()` directly

Comment: The struct is the same, you mean ` Bitmap *image.Image` -> `Bitmap image.Image`. The program was working, was I just lucky?

Comment: @coulix, oops, yes

Comment: @coulix, you weren't "lucky", it will work this way, but there's no reason for it, and only makes life difficult.

Comment: `(*img.Bitmap).Bounds()` I am now getting an ./image.go:65: invalid indirect of img.Bitmap (type image.Image). At this point I dont need to dereference `img.Bitmap` right?

Comment: @coulix: yes. If you get rid of the unnecessary pointer, you don't have to dereference it.

Comment: Good answer JimB, especially for pointing out pointer to interface not being ideal.